# distribution of normalized random weights

Tags: random-variable, weights, weighted-mean

**TL;DR:**
Given a finite series of *positive* and *iid* random variates/weights $w_i$ of *known* distribution, $(w_1, ... w_n)$, what is the distribution (or at least the exp.val. and variance) of the normalized random variates, defined by
$$
\lambda_i := \frac{w_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n w_j}
$$
One may assume any reasonable distribution for $w_i$, if this simplifies anything. For example $w_i\sim\mathcal{U}([0.9,1.1])$. Intuitivley it is clear, that $\text{Exp}[\lambda_i]=1/n$, but I wasn't even able to show this.

**Problem:** This problem arises in the estimation of weighted averages
$$
\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n w_i x_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n w_i} = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_i x_i
$$
when the weights are themselves random variates. There's much literature for fixed weights, but I found nothing to solve the above for the case of random weights.

When the distribution is not an accessable quantity, I am also intereested in the moments or other information about the $\lambda_i$.

**My attempt**:
The main problem I encountered is the treatment of the inverse of the sum of the weights.  Assuming a sufficiently large $n$, setting $\mu:=\text{Exp}[w_i]$ and $\sigma^2:=\text{Var}[w_i]$  and defining
$$
W := \sum_{j=1}^n w_j
$$
the central limit theorem yields $W \sim \mathcal{N}(n\mu, \sqrt{n}\sigma)$. Now the  variate $1/W$ has a shifted [reciprocal normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution). From this fact I was able to derive the exp.val. of $1/W$ (with the formula given in the wikipedia)
$$
\text{Exp}\left[\frac{1}{W}\right] = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} F\left(\frac{n\mu}{\sqrt{2n}\sigma}\right)
$$
where $F$ is the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function). But to further calculate the exp.val. of the $\lambda_i$ one also needs the covariance of $W$ and $w_i$, which I dont know how to derive.
$$
\text{Exp}\left[\lambda_i\right] =  \text{Exp}\left[\frac{1}{W}\cdot w_i\right] = \text{Exp}\left[\frac{1}{W}\right]\text{Exp}\left[w_i\right]  + \text{Cov}\left[w_i,\frac{1}{W}\right]
$$
Any ideas or hints where to go from here, or is there another and easier approach?

Comment: As an example of an effective approach, note that since $\sum_{i}\lambda_i=1,$ for any $j$ $$1 = E\left[\sum_i \lambda_i\right] = \sum_{i}E[\lambda_i] = \sum_{i}E[\lambda_j] = nE[\lambda_j]$$ implies $E[\lambda_j]=1/n.$ You can wring similar information out of a variance calculation. To get a full answer you usually need to make approximations or work with explicit distributions.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't see that - so elegant!